# where conf directory in maven when one installed by brew in mac to change settings.xm

Tags: macos, maven, config, settings

Not able to find that where is conf file of maven, once one installed it by brew in mac to change settings.xm

I run following command and could not find:

```
    devu@devu-mac 1.0.14 % pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/mvnvm/1.0.14
devu@devu-mac 1.0.14 % which mvn
/usr/local/bin/mvn
devu@devu-mac 1.0.14 % ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvn
lrwxr-xr-x  1 devu  admin  30 Feb 17 20:50 /usr/local/bin/mvn -> ../Cellar/mvnvm/1.0.14/bin/mvn
devu@devu-mac 1.0.14 % ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/mvnvm/1.0.14 
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 devu  admin    741 Feb 17 20:50 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--  1 devu  admin  11345 May 11  2020 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 devu  admin   2094 May 11  2020 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 devu  admin    128 Feb 17 20:50 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 devu  admin     96 Feb 17 20:50 libexec
devu@devu-mac 1.0.14 % ls -l
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 devu  admin    741 Feb 17 20:50 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--  1 devu  admin  11345 May 11  2020 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 devu  admin   2094 May 11  2020 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 devu  admin    128 Feb 17 20:50 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 devu  admin     96 Feb 17 20:50 libexec
devu@devu-mac 1.0.14 % ls -l bin 
total 16
-r-xr-xr-x  1 devu  admin  155 Feb 17 20:50 mvn
-r-xr-xr-x  1 devu  admin  160 Feb 17 20:50 mvnDebug
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Change `settings.xml`? Or something else?

Comment: yes @JFabianMeier

Comment: If you want your own `settings.xml`, you'll put a file named `settings.xml` into the `.m2` directory in your user directory. Usually, you do not make any changes in the maven installation itself.

Comment: @JFabianMeier that don't look like a clear approach because one can delete the .m2 directory sometimes.

Comment: It is the recommended approach to only change the `settings.xml` in the `.m2` directory. First of all, you never delete the `.m2` directory. You may delete the `.m2/repository` directory if you have broken local repository. Secondly, this way you'll keep the `settings.xml` when you'll update Maven.